# Memory usage of Windows Phone app keeps building up when going back and forth between pages

Tags: image, memory-management, garbage-collection, windows-phone

I am writing a **sample Windows Phone 8.1 app** which is just an album maker. From the app, I can choose photos from the gallery and make them into an album.

**Features**:-

1. If albums have been previously created by me, then the first picture of each album is displayed when I start my app.(Lets call this page *'AllAlbumsView'*)
2. If I click on any picture in *AllAlbumsView*, then I am taken to that specific album(Lets call this page *'EditPage'*) and can view pictures of that album.
3. If I click back button from *EditPage*, I am again taken to the *AllAlbumsView.*

Now, the **problem that I am facing** is: Even if I have just one album having just three pictures, and if I go from *AllAlbumsView* to the *EditPage* and then back to the *AllAlbumsView* by clicking on the back button and do this **again and again**, the memory used by app keeps on building.

I investigated this through the **memory diagnostic tool** of Visual Studio and found that when I went from *EditPage* to *AllAlbumsView*, the memory usage didn't go down(i.e. the images of the album which was being viewed are still in memory). Then when I opened the *EditPage* again by clicking on the album, the memory usage increased as images were again loaded.(So, I have multiple copies of images in memory)

**What I want is**: When I go to *EditPage* the Images should be loaded into memory but when I go back to the *AllAlbumsView* page, the images should be discarded automatically by the `garbage collector`. Right now, the `garbage-collector` is not cleaning up the images in memory when I go back to the *AllAlbumsViewPage*

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not clearing the references of Objects you are using.

Ok,you can do this before loading Startup `AllAlbumsView` page in `OnNavigatedTo` handler:

```
Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   while (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
   {
      NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
   }
});
```

so that on back press when `OnNavigatedTo` is called your stack is empty so no memory should be occupied,you can go to next screen, then again back, again stack empty and so on...Thats it.Also, you must be sure that you are just `ovveriding BackKeyPress` event handler no new Navigation should be there.Hope this helps.

Comment: @vits...thanks..just one problem....is NavigationService class available for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: If your project is WP8.1 Silverlight then YES, as you are having Page. If its Windows Phone RunTime then you need to use "Frame.Navigate(typeof(NextPage))" So you need to use Frame as [this](http://www.programering.com/a/MTO5QjMwATA.html). It it helped you dont forget to accept my answer.Cheers.